# data not binding through component class method

Tags: angular

I have this simple code in my app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'portfolio';
  data: string;
  dataArray: number [] = [];

  onSubmit(){
    var initData = []

    initData = this.data.split('\n')


    for(var i=0; i<initData.length; i++){
      if(isNaN(parseFloat(initData[i])) == false && initData[i] != null){
        this.dataArray[i] = parseFloat(initData[i])
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and in my template:

```
<form (submit) = "onSubmit()">
    <textarea rows="20" cols = "10" name="what" [(ngModel)] = "data"></textarea>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<h1>{{dataArray}}</h1>
```

For some reason dataArray does not show anything unless I add this.dataArray =[] to the onSubmit method.  Can anyone please explain to me why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

To display object state of array in json format you need to use `json` pipe, like that:

```
<form (submit) = "onSubmit()">
    <textarea rows="20" cols = "10" name="what" [(ngModel)] = "data"></textarea>
    <input type='submit'>
</form>

<h1>{{dataArray | json}}</h1>
```

Here is [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-p5mcfl?file=src/app/app.component.html). If you just bind an object to template,  it uses it's default string representation, which is not suitable. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the culprit for this behavior is `dataArray`. It's an array and on submit you do not change it, you just push the elements into it, but if you do `this.dataArray = []` in `onSubmit` method, you change an array and Angular {{...}} interpolation thinks it needs to be updated in template. So if you change in template `<h1>{{dataArray}}</h1>` to something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of dataArray">
  {{ data }}
</div>
```

you'll see the changes on submit.